# Convert kebab to Title case and add single quote

Tags: c#

I already created a function that converts the kebab case to title case. however the last one I have trouble converting it. basically for single separated character (s only), I need to add a '.

```
basketball-and-football
tennis-soccer
women-s-dress

to

Basketball And Football
Tennis Soccer
Women's Dress

private static string ConvertToTitle(string val)
    {
        var text = val.Replace("-", " ");
        TextInfo textInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
        return textInfo.ToTitleCase(text);
    }
```

Comment: But won't your suggestion fail for things like `a-summer-of-sun` (sorry can't think of a better example, but you get the idea) to `A'summer Of Sun`? I think you would have to special case the possessive `s. Maybe it is sufficient to change "for single separated character, I need to add a '" to "for single separated s, I need to add a ' and keep the case as lower case".

Comment: yes youre right. I need to consider the separated 's' only. thanks

Comment: I'm tempted to say use `var text = val.Replace("-s-", "'s-");` but that wont work for `'s` at the end of the string.

Comment: @SlackGroverglow, you could probably use `Regex.Replace` to replace "-s" with "'s" if it precedes another "-" or ends the string. I'm bad with regular expressions so I can't say exactly how but that's almost certainly the neatest solution. Otherwise, do as you suggest and then add a special case for "-s" at the end.